# Why did I create this table? Counting letter frequencies maybe

Tags: mystery, letters, unsolved-mysteries

This is a real puzzle, in the sense that I'm puzzled by what I've found.

I stumbled upon a google sheet in my google drive.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JpUIY8w0436rz61Fp6rPIynBh4_Xm7fNwJRb681xljQ/edit?usp=sharing

The first column contains the (Swedish) alphabet, one letter on each row. The second and third columns are manually entered numbers. The fourth column is the difference between the second and third column. The fifth and sixth column contains a few manually entered numbers.

This info was input on friday the 28th of August 2015 at 9 pm.

What could I possibly have been doing? Does anyone see a sensible pattern here?

Comment: It has to be 2 sets of letter frequencies, although all the extra letters are in column B, suggesting that 6 letters were added to text 2. They're E,L,N and D,T,Z, which obviously can't make a word. Any idea why it's titled Kamera?

Comment: The title "Kamera" is most likely not related. Looking at the version history, I used the same document to compare cameras earlier.

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site. Could you please "convert" your spread-sheet and post it directly here? It is not so good to have some links to some offsite place here...

Comment: It's not so much in the spirit of Puzzling, but could you give some more context about what you generally were doing in August 2015. Were you a student?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All letters appearing in a set of hundred can only be

> Scrabble.

> The frequencies of the left columns almost match the number of copies of each letter in swedish scrabble.
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions#Swedish

> Now what did you do with these?  Since the second column has more than 100 letters,
>   it is more than a full set.
>   It could be that you tried to figure which are the extra letters.
>   Maybe someone cheated and you tried to figure whose word it was, that added the
>   extra letters.

Comment: It's incredibly close though it doesn't appear to be a *perfect* match according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scrabble_letter_distributions#Swedish) - Column C is almost spot on but for an extra AEOT... Surely it must be related! +1 for the insight :) (EDIT: I see you spotted and noted this discrepancy at the same time!)

Comment: This does sound like a very compelling explanation. I have played a lot of Wordfeud (scrabble app), and I have played in both Swedish and English, so it would make sense that I compared letter frequencies at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be:

> Frequency of letters in two very similar passages of text?

Comment: literally just reread the title and realised you already came to this possible conclusion...

Comment: Hmm yes, but the words "very similar" in your answer gave me an idea. Perhaps we should look into what can be created given the two sets of letters... or their difference.

Comment: @gibson as a non-swede i don't think I'd be much help on that front....

Answer (score 1):

Not a full answer, but maybe it will help you get closer:

Assuming these are let frequencies:

- the distribution is quite flat. It's surprising (to me) that a text with only 102 letters contain all letters except q and w. The Scrabble letter distribution suggests that j, y, c, x and z are quite uncommon I'm swedish words
- the letter w is not part of the list
- do the letters `d, e, l, n, t, z` mean anything to you? It doesn't match any swedish dictionary words

Could it be two lists with "tags"? Both lists are multiple of both 2 and 3, so maybe a list with:

```
Fe
Ca
Xl
Ka
...
```

Possibly with numbers behind (fa 8342). Then you might have used this to figure out which elements were missing in one list. De lt and nz (or dt, le, nz or ...) were missing in the first list.